# throwing exception from WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

---

---

I am trying to throw an exception from WCF module to the client module. I am getting the following error "FaultException was unhandled by the user"

**at the service side**

```
public IList<UserEntity> SearchUserDetail(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        int y = 0;
        int u = 9 / y;
        return new UserViewModel().SearchUserDetail(userName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException(
        new FaultReason(ex.Message),new FaultCode("Data Access Error"));
    }                 
}
```

**at the client side**

```
try
{             
    ServiceReference.ServiceClient servRef = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();

    List<UserEntity> users = new List<UserEntity>();
    users.AddRange(servRef.SearchUserDetail("Jacson"));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = users;            
}
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException  exc)
{
    Logging.Log(new Exception("Search User", exc));
}
```

In the app.config of the Service module I have added the following attribute

```
 serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"
```

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: On the service side code - Unless you are logging the data (which I don't see that you are), this sort of exception re-throwing will cause your application to become much harder to debug.  You're basically throwing away the stack trace.  Don't do that.  Or if you do, log it first.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the FaultContractAttribute to the method `SearchUserDetail`, if it has the OperationContractAttribute and is part of your ServiceContract class.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyServiceContract
{
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(...)]
  IList<UserEntity> SearchUserDetail(string userName)
}
```

I'm not sure about the type of the FaultContract. But have a look at msdn.

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug:

- [First part of the explanation](http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2009/02/handling-exception-right-way-in-wcf.html)
- [Second part](http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2009/02/handling-exceptions-right-way-in-wcf.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm way late here, but just in case anybody stumbles upon this, I was having the same error and everything was ok in my code.

It turns out this only happened in the Visual Studio environment due to some debugging options. See [here](http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/systemservicemodelfaultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code/) for an explanation.